# TypeError: DataFrame.pivot() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a problem when running this code:

```
ax=sns.heatmap(clasificacion.pivot("Rapida","Lenta",'Máximo Drawdown'), annot=False, fmt=".3", linewidths=0, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: DataFrame.pivot() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the `pivot` method is:

```py
DataFrame.pivot(index=None, columns=None, values=None)
```

Here's how you can correct your code:

```py
ax = sns.heatmap(clasificacion.pivot(index="Rapida", columns="Lenta", values='Máximo Drawdown'), 
                 annot=False, 
                 fmt=".3f", 
                 linewidths=0, 
                 cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```